# VBA function: Find same string multiple times, use offset to generate sum, terminate at the end of dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function which dynamically generates a range based on where the function is called from.  It should then iterate from the top of that range looking for a string matching the string at the beginning of the row where the function is called from.  When a string matches it will add a value two columns over to a sum.  Once it has iterated through the range it should terminate.

Here I have two solutions that almost work.  Both fail on the code that does the summing, but work absolutely fine otherwise.  I have commented out where each fails.

```
Function Average_Power()
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngLast As Range, rngFound As Range, cell As Range
    Dim CallerAddr As String, strFirstAddress As String, strFamilyName As String, teststring As String
    Dim Sum As Double

    Sum = 0
    teststring = ""

    With Application.Caller
        CallerAddr = .Address
    End With

    strFamilyName = Application.Caller.Offset(0, -3).Value

    Set rngSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("B15", Range(CallerAddr))

    Set rngLast = rngSearch.Cells(rngSearch.Cells.Count)

    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=strFamilyName, After:=rngLast, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    For Each cell In rngSearch.Cells
'        If InStr(cell.Value, strFamilyName) Then
'            Sum = Sum + cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
'        End If
    Next cell

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address
        Sum = Sum + rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Do
'            Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
'            Sum = Sum + rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Loop Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
    End If

    Average_Power = Sum
End Function
```

This is my output at the moment since I am still trying to sum the values, I would be looking for the final Average Power to be 6000 (The sum of 4000 and 2000):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMHEz.png

ERROR: "There are one ore more circular references where a formula refers to its own cell either directly or indirectly.  This might cause them to calculate incorrectly.  Try removing or changing these references, or moving the formulas to a different cells"  I guess the solution might be if there were a way to move the range one column to the left so that the function isn't iterated over? (this would still include all necessary cells to do the calculation)

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you  are trying to do, if you would mock up some data and expected output and edit your post to insert that information.

Comment: It would also help if you can indicate which error**s** are raised by the respective lines of code.

Comment: Quick comment too - I would avoid using `Sum` as a variable name, as it's close to the reserved word in VBA.  I personally use like, `iTotal` or `mySum`...

Comment: You can use `=SUMIF($A$2:$A2,$A2,$C$2:$C2)` Assuming your data starts in A1, Put that in D2 and copy down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that `.FindNext` is not usable in the context of a `UDF`. This is not surprising; because `.FindNext` needs to rely on memorizing and updating some "state" on the worksheet, and UDF's are not allowed to change the state.

However, working around it with yet another `.Find` seems to solve the issue. Besides, I noticed that your way of iterating over the matches is not accurate. Your code can be re-written like this:

```
Function Average_Power() As Double
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String, strFamilyName As String

    strFamilyName = Application.caller.Offset(0, -3).Value
    Set rngSearch = Application.caller.Parent.Range("B15", Application.caller)
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=strFamilyName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If rngFound Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address
    Do
       Average_Power = Average_Power + rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value

       ' FindNext re-written like this will work:
       Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=strFamilyName, After:=rngFound, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       ''''''''''''                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    Loop Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
End Function
```

Comment: Yup, this did it.  Totally wasn't thinking about the parameters in the Find method.  Thanks!